# VBS issue for writing a file

Tags: vbscript

Here is what I am trying to do.

The script reads a text file for computer names one at a time.

Checks to see if a program.lnk exists.
If the link exists it copies a new link to that computer/users profile.
It then records in a new text file the computer name and that the program exists.
It then removes the original program.lnk file.

If the program.lnk does not exist, it records to the same text file the computer name and that the program does not exist.

The scipt then moves to the next computer name in the list.

I am having problems getting the ComputerListModified.txt file to be created if it doesn't exist but append the file if it does exist.

Here is the Code I have....

```
InputFile = "C:\scripts\computers.txt"
Const DeleteReadOnly = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Do While Not (objFile.AtEndOfStream)
strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
For Each objsubfolder In objFSO.GetFolder("\\" & strComputer & "\c$\Documents and    Settings\").subfolders

If objFSO.FileExists(objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Wellcore Operations.LNK") Then
objFSO.CopyFile "\\pc01130\c$\scripts\Wellcore OperationsReadOnly.lnk", (objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\")
outFile="c:\scripts\ComputerListModified.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write strComputer: objFile.Write  " This Computer had Wellcore Operations" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

Else

outFile="c:\scripts\ComputerListModified.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write strComputer: objFile.Write " This Computer did not have Wellcore Operations" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

End If

If objFSO.FileExists(objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Wellcore Operations.LNK") Then
objFSO.DeleteFile (objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Wellcore Operations.LNK")

End If
Next
Loop

MsgBox "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log relevant facts in a (deeply nested) repeated action, you'll have to write to the file in your innermost loop. But preparing (and closing) the file is a top level task, it shouldn't be done in the loop(s).

Mr. Gates did design the .OpenTextFile method correctly. It can be used without any .FileExists checks.

Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForAppending = 8

Dim goFS  : Set goFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim gsLog : gsLog     = ".\logdemo.log"
WScript.Echo gsLog, "exists:", CStr(goFS.FileExists(gsLog))
'                           .OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
Dim goLog : Set goLog = goFS.OpenTextFile(gsLog, ForAppending, True)
goLog.WriteLine Now & " start"

Dim sComputer
For Each sComputer In Split("alpha beta gamma")
    Dim sFolder
    For Each sFolder in Split("A B C")
        goLog.WriteLine Join(Array(Now, sComputer, sFolder))
    Next
Next

goLog.WriteLine Now & " end"
goLog.WriteLine "-------------------------"
goLog.Close
```

output:

```
cscript logdemo.vbs
.\logdemo.log exists: False

type logdemo.log
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM start
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM alpha A
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM alpha B
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM alpha C
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM beta A
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM beta B
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM beta C
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM gamma A
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM gamma B
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM gamma C
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM end
-------------------------

cscript logdemo.vbs
.\logdemo.log exists: True

type logdemo.log
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM start
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM alpha A
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM alpha B
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM alpha C
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM beta A
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM beta B
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM beta C
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM gamma A
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM gamma B
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM gamma C
6/12/2013 9:25:26 PM end
-------------------------
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM start
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM alpha A
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM alpha B
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM alpha C
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM beta A
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM beta B
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM beta C
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM gamma A
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM gamma B
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM gamma C
6/12/2013 9:26:00 PM end
-------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me.  I was able to see what you were doing here and able to make it fit for my use.